# text view not centrally aligned in tab layout perfectly in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-tabstrip

I am using tab layout for my application , but when i try to use this i want to make sure that text i set for tab layout should be center aligned, i tried different tutorials in which i have succeeded but with some issues. Whenever i click on tab the text of the tabs move sort of upward slightly making my screen disturb also when i first click on that screen there is grayish line beneath the tab. I have used `android:tabStripEnabled="false"` but its of no use

Here is my xml

```
<TabHost
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonclientoption" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my code

```
public TabHost tabHost;
public int currentTab = 0;
public int lastTab = 0;
public static final String caseno = "";
public static final String amountcalc = "";
String useridmain1 = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clientoption);
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.header);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    TextView tt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1header);
    tt1.setText("My Client");
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String useridmain = extras.getString("homefraguserid");
        System.out.println("useridhome" + useridmain);
        useridmain1 = useridmain;
    }

    // ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    // bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new
    // ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#058B96")));
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    // tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("New Business");
    photospec.setIndicator("New Business");
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, NewBuisness.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    // Tab for Songs
    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Client Services");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    // songspec.setIndicator("Client Services");
    songspec.setIndicator("Client Services");

    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Clientservices.class);
    songsIntent.putExtra("username", useridmain1);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title); // Unselected Tabs

        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#058B96"));

        tv.setGravity(0);

    }

    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
            .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#058B96")); // selected

    TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentTabView().findViewById(
            android.R.id.title); // for Selected Tab

    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    tv.setGravity(0);

    int tabCount2 = tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < tabCount2; i++) {
        final View view = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i);
        if (view != null) {
            // reduce height of the tab
            view.getLayoutParams().height *= 0.60;

            // get title text view
            final View textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            if (textView instanceof TextView) {
                // just in case check the type

                // center text
                ((TextView) textView).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                // wrap text
                ((TextView) textView).setSingleLine(false);

                // explicitly set layout parameters
                textView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
                textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            }
        }
    }

    // Tab for Videos
    getTabHost().setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId)

        {

            for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)

            {

                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                        .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); // unselected

                TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget()
                        .getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); // Unselected
                                                                            // Tabs

                tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#058B96"));
                tv.setGravity(0);
            }

            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#058B96")); // selected

            TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getCurrentTabView()
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.title); // for Selected Tab

            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            tv.setGravity(0);
            /*
             * 
             * currentTab = getTabHost().getCurrentTab();
             * 
             * 
             * 
             * setCurrentTabColor();
             * 
             * 
             * 
             * lastTab = currentTab;
             */

        }

    });

    getTabWidget().getChildAt(lastTab).setBackgroundColor(
            Color.parseColor("#058B96"));
}

public void setCurrentTabColor() {
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(currentTab).setBackgroundColor(
            Color.parseColor("#058B96"));
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(lastTab).setBackgroundColor(
            Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
}
```